# Need SQL guru for a complex query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have several tables that I am trying to get some data out of, and I am very close, but cannot quite close the deal.

I have the following tables:

- EVENT
- USER
- FRIEND
- USER__FRIEND
- EVENT__INVITATION

USER and FRIEND are linked via the USER__FRIEND table (which contains a USER_ID and a FRIEND_ID field)

EVENT__INVITATION links an EVENT with a FRIEND (it has EVENT_ID and INVITEE_ID)

I am trying to get all EVENTS where:

- I am the EVENT creator ($myUserID = EVENT.CREATOR_ID)
- or I am invited to the event ($myUserID = EVENT__INVITATION.INVITEE_ID)
- or one of my FRIENDs is the creator of the EVENT ($myUserID = USER__FRIEND.USER_ID AND EVENT.CREATOR_ID IN (list of my FRIENDs))
- or one of my FRIENDs is invited to the EVENT ($myUserID = USER__FRIEND.USER_ID AND EVENT__INVITATION.INVITEE_ID IN (list of my FRIENDs))

There are some other WHERE conditions around other parameters, but I think I can sort those out on my own.

Right now the only way I could get this to work was with a UNION, which I think must be a cop-out, and if I had better chops I could get around using it.

So, the question is, can this be done with a single, inexpensive query that does not use a UNION?

Here is what I have so far, which accomplishes everything except the EVENTs that my FRIENDs are invited to (23 is the passed in userID in this case):

```
SELECT e.*
FROM event e
LEFT JOIN event__invitation ei ON ei.event_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN user__friend uf ON uf.friend_id = ei.invitee_id
LEFT JOIN friend f ON f.id = uf.friend_id
WHERE (ei.invitee_id = 23 OR e.creator_id = 23 OR uf.user_id = 23 OR f.user_id = e.creator_id)
AND e.start_time >= 1348000000
```

and this is the query with the UNION:

```
SELECT e.* FROM event e
INNER JOIN event__invitation ei ON ei.event_id = e.id
INNER JOIN user__friend uf ON uf.friend_id = ei.invitee_id
WHERE (e.creator_id = 23 OR ei.invitee_id = 23 OR uf.user_id = 23)
UNION
SELECT e1.* FROM event e1
WHERE e1.creator_id IN (
    SELECT f1.user_id FROM friend f1
    INNER JOIN user__friend uf1 ON uf1.friend_id = f1.id
    WHERE uf1.user_id = 23
    AND f1.user_id IS NOT NULL
);
```

There is more to the query that makes the use of the UNION undesireable.  I have a complex trig calculation that I am doing in the main select, and am ordering the results by that value.  I think may mess up the result set.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing the ones where the friend is the creator?

Comment: I know it feels more manly to do it all in one big join, but I suspect the UNION is more efficient.

Comment: @Crazy: No that one is in there (look at the last OR of the WHERE clause).

Comment: @Barmar: LOL!  I agree, but one problem I have is there are other parts of the query that the UNION may interfere with.  I am doing a complex trig calc and ordering by the result, so the UNION would mess up the order and require the calc to be done again.

Comment: What is the relationship between the FRIEND and USER tables? Are they 1 to 1? Are user ids and friend ids the same (you test both invitee_id and user_id against the value 23)?

Comment: Distance calculation? Can't you return the lat/long as part of the union, and do the calculation on the result? Something like `SELECT *, <complex trig>  distance from (<union query>) u order by distance`.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion: No, they are many-to-many, with USER__FRIEND between them.

Comment: @Barmar Well, that seems like a great idea, but I am already doing a sub-select for the calculation.  Will that matter?

Comment: Right now the query looks like this `SELECT <complex calc> as distance, EVENT.* FROM (SELECT <narrowing query for distance>) JOIN, JOIN, JOIN, WHERE... ORDER BY distance`.  Would I just put the JOINs inside of the sub-select of the FROM clause?

Comment: @Raconteur I'm confused, it seems like if you find a user__friend with .user_id = yourself and .friend_id = ei.invitee_id that what you're saying is you've found one of your friends that's invited to the list. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle with some sample data to play with?

Comment: @Crazy No, you are dead on.  That is correct.  The difficult bit, which I guess I did not describe accurately is that EI.INVITEE_ID will point to FRIEND.ID, whereas EVENT.CREATOR_ID will point to FRIEND.USER_ID.

Comment: @Barmar What a great idea!  Why didn't I think of that!  :P

Comment: @Raconteur So does the first part of the union include friends that are invited to events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following:

```
-- take only distinct events
SELECT DISTINCT e.*
-- start with the event
FROM event e
-- expand to include all invitees and their user_friend info
LEFT JOIN event__invitation ei 
    ON ei.event_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN user__friend invitee
    ON invitee.friend_id = ei.invitee_id
-- now we join again to user_friend to get the friends of the invitees/the creator
LEFT JOIN user__friend invitedFriend
    ON invitedFriend.user_id = invitee.user_id
        OR invitedFriend.user_id = e.creator_id
-- finally we match on whether any of these friends of friends are myself
LEFT JOIN friend myselfAsAFriend
    ON myselfAsAFriend.id = invitedFriend.friendId
        AND myselfAsAFriend.userID = 23
WHERE 
(   
    -- (1) I am the creator of the event
    e.creator_id = 23 
    -- (2) I am invited to the event
    OR invitee.user_id = 23 
    -- (3 and 4) for this join to match a friend of mine must be invited or the creator
    OR myselfAsAFriend.id IS NOT NULL 
)
AND e.start_time >= 1348000000
```

Comment: @Barmar (or was the answer from Chase?) -  Sorry for the delay... RL got in the way.  Need to craft some data to put this through its paces, but I think it will work.  Will accept as answer as soon as I get it tested.  Cheers!

Comment: The answer was from Chase, I just fixed a typo in the SQL.

Comment: Thanks Chase, and Barmar.  This was not exactly what I needed but definitely got me 90+% of the way there, and I was able to wrap it up from that.  Appreciate your help, and tenacity!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good at query tuning presently, so I would just give something like this a try and let the optimiser to put its effort in figuring out the best way of getting the results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.*
FROM event e
INNER JOIN event__invitation ei ON ei.event_id = e.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT friend_id
  FROM user__friend
  WHERE user_id = $myUserID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT $myUserID
) u ON u.friend_id IN (e.creator_id, ei.invitee_id)
;
```

If this doesn't prove efficient enough, you could always go with something like [@ChaseMedallion's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12737938/297408), as it may indeed turn out a better one for your case.