# Determine which join added row to result set

Tags: sql, join

I started out with a question in this thread:
[Need SQL guru for a complex query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737572/need-sql-guru-for-a-complex-query)

I now have that solved (thanks to SO), but now need to extract a bit more data.

Let's say I have a query that joins 2 other tables, where criteria in each of the three tables can cause a row to be added to the result set.  Something like:

```
    SELECT a.*
    FROM tableA a
    LEFT JOIN tableB b on a.b_id = b.id
    LEFT JOIN tableC c on a.c_id = c.id
    WHERE a.creator_id = 5 OR b.is_active = 1 OR c.can_attend = 1
```

Whatever the data is... basically what I need to do is determine, for each row in the result set, which criteria allowed it in.  Was it because creator_id was 5, or because it was active, etc.

From this overly simplified example, you could say just look at the data, but notice the data for tables b and c are not being returned, and note that there are a variety of ways in which the join may add the row to the result set.

What I am looking for, I think, is a way to inject a value when a row is added to the result set, or something to that effect.  Will make more sense if you look at the accepted answer in the linked question above.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Not sure where you're going with this, but something in your question makes me think the MERGE statement may be of interest to you: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/ - it lets you insert, update or delete from tables based on join results.

Comment: Hi John, am using MySQL (sorry I did not mention), so not sure if MERGE is part of the vernacular there, although it most likely is... but I am not updating tables.  I am trying to add enough data that I can represent it on-screen in some intelligent fashion, so the info needs to be in the dataset.

Comment: Ahh no worries - MySQL has something similar (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) - should you ever need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a case statement:

```
SELECT a.*,
       (case when b.id is not null and c.id is not null then 'BOTH'
             when b.id is not null and c.id is null then 'B'
             when b.id is null and c.id is not null then 'C'
             else 'A'
        end) as WhereFrom
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b on a.b_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN tableC c on a.c_id = c.id
WHERE a.creator_id = 5 OR b.is_active = 1 OR c.can_attend = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Gordon.  I think this may be what I am looking for, especially given that the criteria for allowing a row into the result set can be a bit complex.  Let me try it out and see if I can get there before I flag is as the answer.